# Check if list view contain item

Tags: c#, listview

i have a listview with 3 columns (id , name, author), i use this method to add row:

```
     public void addToLv(Book book)
    {

        //TODO: Verifier si l'item existe avant d'ajouter
        ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem(book.id.ToString());
        lvi1.Text = book.id.ToString();
        lvi1.SubItems.Add(book.name);
        lvi1.SubItems.Add(carte.author);

        listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);

    }
```

Now i wan't to check if book exists before i insert the new one to avoid duplicate element, i try this code but it'S not working
i have use this line but it's not working:

```
  (listView1.Items.ContainsKey(book.id))
         {
      listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
         }
```

Can you help me please? thank you

Comment: It looks like the SubItems contains the book name.

Comment: Which client library/technology is this?

Comment: Do you mean `book` instead of `carte` in your above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed a "!" (not) in your code.

```
(!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(book.id))
     {
  listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
     }
```

Your code is saying that if your listview contains that key, you will add another entry that has that key. But it seems you want to do the opposite, right? If your listview does not contain an entry with that key, you want to add an entry that has that key.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The key comparison is not case-sensitive. The Name property corresponds to the key for a ListViewItem in the ListView.ListViewItemCollection.

So, you have to set the `Name` in order to use `ContainsKey`

```
lvi1.Name = book.id.ToString();
```

And then the rest like you did:

```
if (!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(book.id.ToString()))
{
     listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are storing your individual names on the [`SubItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx) property, so you'll need to query that to see if a given book name is present. You can do this using a bit of LINQ as follows:

```
// If your ListView doesn't contain any items that have a given book as a SubItem
// then add one
if (!listView1.Items.Any(i => i.SubItems.ContainsKey(book.Name))
{
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
}
```

Since your edit indicates that you actually want to check for the ID instead, which is stored at the ListItem-level, then you would just need to slightly adjust your condition to check the `Text` property since [the `ListViewItem(string)` constructor sets the Text property by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c277wk5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (!listView1.Items.Any(i => i.Text == book.id))
{
     listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i wan't to compare with book.id not book name

Comment: If you want to compare the ID, then you can just use `!listView1.Items.Any(i => i.Text == book.id))` as your condition. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I have an error with Any (CS1061:'listview1' does not contain a definition for 'ANY' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'listview1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).)

Comment: You need to reference LINQ (i.e. `using System.Linq`).

Answer (score 0):

If any thing works, try this:

```
    public void addToLv(Book book)
    {
        //TODO: Verifier si l'item existe avant d'ajouter
        ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem(book.id.ToString());
        //lvi1.Text = book.id.ToString();
        lvi1.SubItems.Add(book.name);
        lvi1.SubItems.Add(carte.author);

        if (!existChecker(book.id.ToString()))
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi1);
    }

    private bool existChecker(string id)
    {
        bool exist = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < lvi1.Items.Count && exist != true; i++)
        {
            if (lvi1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text == id)
                exist = true;
        }
        return exist;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ can't be used for this:

```
if (!listView1.Items.Any(i => i.SubItems.ContainsKey(book.Name))
```

The only real way of doing it is to use the search functionality as thus:

```
if (listView1.FindItemWithText(book.Name) != null)
{
// Do the business...
}
```

etc...