# Prevent adding duplicate snack to ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently stuck on this for 2 hours and did everything I could to find answers but none yet!

```
public class Snack
{
    public string snack { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }

    public Snacks snacks;
    public enum Snacks
    {
        friet,
        kroket,
        frikandel,
        Burger,
    }      
}
```

In the `load` method, I'm initializing my ListView:

```
private void load()
{
    lstSnacks.View = View.Details;
    lstSnacks.Columns.Add("snack");
    lstSnacks.Columns.Add("amount");
    lstSnacks.Columns.Add("price");
        
    cmbSnack.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Snack.Snacks)));
    cmbSnack.SelectedIndex = (int)Snack.Snacks.friet;
}
```

After that, I have a button where I add some snacks with the amount entered in the textbox and a fixed price:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!lstSnacks.Items.ContainsKey(cmbSnack.SelectedItem.ToString()))
    {
        double totalprice = 0;
        Snack snack1 = new Snack();
        snack1.snack = cmbSnack.SelectedItem.ToString(); ;
        snack1.amount = Convert.ToDouble(txtAmount.Text);

        ListViewItem item = lstSnacks.Items.Add(cmbSnack.SelectedItem.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(snack1.amount.ToString());

        if (cmbSnack.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            snack1.price = (int)(snack1.amount * 2.50);

            item.SubItems.Add(snack1.price.ToString());
        }
}
```

I need to look into my ListView and add a snack if it's not already there. If it is, it should tell you that it's already in there, but `items.ContainsKey` is not working for me properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if list view contain item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102322/check-if-list-view-contain-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line...

```
ListViewItem item = lstSnacks.Items.Add(cmbSnack.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

...sets the `Text` property of the ListViewItem. To be able to use `ContainsKey()`, you need to also set its [`Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.name).

One more thing: Consider using [`double.TryParse()`](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse) instead of `Convert.ToDouble()` because there's no guarantee that the user will enter a valid number. When dealing with user input, always favor the `.TryParse()` methods over `Convert.ToXXXX()` or `.Parse()`.

I would change the code into something like this:

```
string itemName = cmbSnack.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (lstSnacks.Items.ContainsKey(itemName))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The item already exists in the list.", "Duplicate item");
    return;
}

if (!double.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, out double amount))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount.", "Incorrect 'Amount' value");
    return;
}

double totalprice = 0;
Snack snack1 = new Snack();
snack1.snack = itemName;
snack1.amount = amount;

ListViewItem item = lstSnacks.Items.Add(itemName);
item.Name = itemName;
item.SubItems.Add(snack1.amount.ToString());

if (cmbSnack.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    snack1.price = (int)(snack1.amount * 2.50);

    item.SubItems.Add(snack1.price.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! very much appriciated!

Comment: @Smmit You're welcome! I've added another note. Check the updated code.